# Fixtures.loadYaml in FunctionalTest didn't really load the data

Tags: playframework, functional-testing, fixtures

I have the following functional test that setup the initial data via fixtures.loadYaml, but when I query the records in testcase, I don't see them. Any reasons?

```
public class UsersTest extends FunctionalTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Fixtures.loadYaml("data.yml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testIndex() {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: What is the console saying? And enable jpa.debugSQL for more info!

Comment: @Zenklys, I didn't see anything from console, after enabling jpa.debugSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation on latest release http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/test, I instead called loadModels, and it worked.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Fixtures.deleteAllModels();
    Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");
}
```